# VSTS External Git

Tags: git, azure-devops

I would like to know if I can still use external Git inside VSTS.
Let say that my company has own git. And, my team would like to use VSTS for task and project management.

Can we use VSTS for integration with our git ?
Instead of moving our project code into VSTS Git, we want VSTS using our company Git and doing integration and monitoring over it.

If yes, which one should I choose ?

import a repository
or 
build code from an external repository

Sorry for this basic question :) hehe

Thank You

Comment: You will get the best integration with VSTS when you use the built in Git. But you can certainly do task and project management and builds and releases using external Git. And of course if you're using external Git, you would choose the external Git option for your builds.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  So if I choose import a repo, it is mean that I migrate from my git into VSTS Git. If I choose build code from external repo, it is means that VSTS is using and monitoring our hosted git. right ?

Comment: Correct. And you probably don't want to import it, because now you'll have to keep them in sync, which is going to be a pain for not much benefit. I'd have it either external, or import it once and then stop using the external at all.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your information. Right now, I am trying to use build code from external repo. I am exploring right now. I am gonna propose VSTS to my team haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using External Git option in Get sources, check the screenshot below:

[image]